# Display only certain fields in ALV

Tags: abap, alv

My table has around 300 columns and I want to display only 10 out of them with specifying which ones. I am working with `CL_SALV_TABLE`.

Can anybody help me with this problem or give me a hint? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the method `SET_VISIBLE` of the Column object (class `CL_SALV_COLUMN`). For more information, see the [chapter "Set the Visibility of the Column" of page "Columns (General)"](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752/7.52.5/en-US?q=Columns%20(General)).

This Minimal reproducible example shows only the columns `SPRAS` and `LAISO` from the table `T002`, all other ones are hidden:

```
  DATA: t002_lines  TYPE TABLE OF t002,
        salv        TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table,
        columns     TYPE salv_t_column_ref.
  FIELD-SYMBOLS <column> TYPE salv_s_column_ref.

  SELECT * FROM t002 INTO TABLE t002_lines.
  CALL METHOD cl_salv_table=>factory
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table = salv
    CHANGING
      t_table      = t002_lines.

  LOOP AT salv->get_columns( )->get( ) ASSIGNING <column>.
    CASE <column>-columnname.
      WHEN 'SPRAS' OR 'LAISO'.
        <column>-r_column->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true ).
      WHEN OTHERS.
        <column>-r_column->set_visible( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>false ).
    ENDCASE.
  ENDLOOP.

  salv->display( ).
```